# Atom: Pylint - false negative when trying to import numpy

Tags: python, numpy, atom-editor, pylint, fedora-26

So, I've got a python project that requires numpy. I have successfully installed numpy and importing it works just fine, but pylint is saying that numpy cannot be imported.

The project is located on another hdd that is mounted at:

> /run/media/user/misc/

The project is in:

> /run/media/user/misc/pythonprojects/testing/

Here's my sample code:

```
import numpy
print(numpy.random.randn())
```

The code works just fine, but pylint is reporting:

> E0401 Unable to import 'numpy'

I'm using [Atom](https://atom.io/) as editor, using the [linter-pylint](https://atom.io/packages/linter-pylint) atom package for linting using pylint and using Fedora 26 as my OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem by installing pylint locally for my user using pip.